# "TypeError: second argument to Function.prototype.apply must be an Array-like object" in node childProcess internal file

Tags: node.js, logging, child-process, console.log

**Disclaimer**: Sorry for lack of infos on this error. I let it there for reference because I couldn't find another question on the subject and it could put people on a track for a solution [Edit] I managed to solve it, see answer below

**Some notes**:

- the error always appear around (not exactly at) the same time when runnning my script
- This error kills my process asynchronously
- It appear to happens when logging a lot of content (actually a big array of numbers in a for loop)

Here is a screenshot where you can see the code / stack trace

[image]

**Context:** I'm spawning a child process to run my tests so that I can rerun them if they fail while taking in account any modification made in the test code (since ES6 import this is very difficult since we can't no more clear import cache and reimport files)

Tried on Node `v18.18.2` and `v20.11.1`

I can provide the code, but it's huge and I'm not sure it will be relevant here. Let me know if you need further details or code examples.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get rid of this error by deleting a line that logged a very long array of numbers in a for loop.

So I went from

```js
console.log('a string', veryLongNumberArray)
```

to

```js
console.log('a string')
```

Sorry that I don't have more clues but those lines, I let that for further references and because I think ot may help at least to give a track for a solution